Map from $[-1,1]\to S^1$ that are continuous at exactly $1$ or $0$ points?
The following is a problem from a GRE review booklet:
Let $f$ be a function with domain $[-1,1]$, such that the coordinates of each point $(x,y)$ of its graph satisfy $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. The total number of points at which $f$ is necessarily continuous is... ?
My solution was to define the map $f$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-x^2}\quad\quad \textrm{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2}\quad \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Which is discontinuous at all points in $(-1,1)$ but continuous at the two points $-1$ and $1$.
This leads me to believe that every map from $[-1,1]\to S^1$ must necessarily be continuous at two points. According to the answer key, this is indeed the correct solution.
I am confused, however, on why it is not possible for such a map to exist with zero or only $1$ point of continuity. I tried proving an arbitrary map from $[-1,1]\to S^1$ must be continuous at two points using contradiction, but couldn't get anywhere. Does anyone have any insight? Thank you.

Hint: $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \cdot \alpha(x)$ where $\alpha(x)= \pm 1$ (in particular it is bounded). What can you say then about $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x)$?

@mihaild I'm confused by your comment. I was asking in general about a map from $[-1,1]\to S$ which only has one or zero points of continuity. I am aware that the function I provided (and that you restate) will have limits converging at $1$ and $-1$.

No, @mihaild did not restate your function, but instead gave a general formula for a general function $f(x)$ as in your problem, expressed in terms of a general notation for a general function $\alpha : [-1,+1] \to {-1,+1}$.

"Let $f$ be a function with domain $[-1,1]$, such that the coordinates of each point $(x,y)$ of its graph satisfy $x^2 + y^2 = 1$."  This means that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$ and not $S^1$. The graph of $f$ is then a subset of the plane. Please correct your question if you agree.

Due to Paul Frost's comment it does not make sense to consider a function $f : [-1,1] \to S^1$. Instead we have to take a function $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that the graph $G(f) = \{(x,f(x)) \mid X \in [-1,1]\}$ is contained in $S^1$.
This means that $x^2 + f(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Therefore $\lvert f(x) \rvert = \sqrt{1- x^2}$. In particular $f(\pm 1) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \pm 1} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0$. The latter implies $\lim_{x \to \pm 1} f(x)  = 0 = f(\pm 1)$ so that $f$ is continuous at the two points $\pm 1$.
Your example shows that there exists $f$ which is discontinuous at all $x \in (-1,1)$.

As we have ascertained in comments and answers, such function must be continuous at $-1$ and $+1$. I would rather prove this directly from the definition. Say we want to prove that $f$ is continuous at $1$. So we take an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Now we observe that
$$
x^2+f(x)^2=1 \ \Rightarrow\ \lvert f(x)\rvert=\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x}.$$
Therefore, for all $x\in [-1, 1]$ such that $1-x<\delta$,
$$
\lvert f(x)\rvert\le \sqrt{2\delta}.$$
Taking $\delta=\epsilon^2/2$ we conclude the check that $f$ is continuous at $1$.
Since $g(x)=f(-x)$ also satisfies $x^2+g(x)^2=1$, and by the above argument $g$ is continuous at $1$, we conclude that $f$ is continuous at $-1$ too.

$f:[-1,1] \to S^1$ is some function that can be represented as $e^{if(x)}$ which in turn has a neat expression, $$e^{if(x)} = \cos(f(x))+i(\sin(f(x))$$
Now recall complex continuity, our map is continuous iff both the real part and the imaginary part are continuous, so for our map to not be cont. for no $x$ are both $\cos(f(x))$ and $\sin(f(x))$ continuous.
Now the outer functions are differentiable, so this means that for discontinuity everywhere the Taylor series of $\sin(f(x))$ does not exist anywhere, in other words,
$$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{(n)}(f(a))}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ does not converge for any $a$. But we know this is just:
$$f(a)-\frac{f(a)^3}{3!}+\frac{f(a)^5}{5!}- \dots $$
Now to "deny" the trivial convergence we must have that $\forall a f(a) \neq0$, but this is not true, there's at least $1$ such $a$, because we must have $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ in our graph. But we need two distinct $a$ to satisfy these points. The proof is now complete.

This does not really prove anything, I'm afraid. Sure, $f(1)=f(-1)=0$, hence the series for sine converges at these two points. However, there is nothing you can infer from this (trivial) statement. Taylor series are only significant when they converge on an interval.

Thank you for pointing this out! As a contrarian wanted to try a different technique since the strong hint in the comments was already given.
